Are the vast majority of irrational numbers, transcendental?
It is often stated that the vast majority of real numbers are irrational.  Does it also follow that the vast majority of irrational numbers are transcendental?

Yes, but in practice we don't know for the vast majority of irrational numbers, whether they are transcendental or not. For example, we know that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational. But is it transcendental? We don't know.

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/813287/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822919/42969

There are only countably many algebraic numbers since there are only countably many polynomials with rational coefficients. So yes, almost all real numbers are transcendental.

+1 though perhaps worth noting "since there are only countably many polynomials with rational coefficients and they each have a finite number of roots"
